# Need better solution to current JSON unordered list

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am still in the processing of learning JSON and JS and I know this is not the correct way to do this. I have a bunch of loops because i need specific items to show in my unordered list. I am hoping someone can help me out and make this code better formatted and i know there must be a better way to do this. You will see I am targeting each item by its ID and showing the item in the UL.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';

    $.ajax({
     dataType: "jsonp",
     url: '',
     success: function(data){

        var recipeIngredients = "<ul class='recIngLink'>";

        recipeIngredients += "<li>" + '2 tbsp butter' + "</li>";

        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            if (item._id == "57911b238d30bc8e78002cf2") { 
                recipeIngredients += "<li>" + '3 tbsp ' + item.itemName + "</li>"; 
            }
        });

        recipeIngredients += "<li>" + '1 onion, finely chopped' + "</li>";

        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            if (item._id == "5846df5e06552ba30a00000d") { 
                recipeIngredients += "<li>" + '2 cloves ' + item.itemName + ', crushed' + "</li>"; 
            }
        });

        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            if (item._id == "585c1f57fd50cb0000000257") { 
                recipeIngredients += "<li>" + '1 ½ cups ' + item.itemName + "</li>"; 
            }
        });

        recipeIngredients += "<li>" + '1 cup pumpkin, diced' + "</li>";

        recipeIngredients += "<li>" + '½ cup chopped parsley, optional' + "</li>";

        recipeIngredients += "</ul>";       

        $('#recipeIngredients').append(recipeIngredients);

      }
   });
});
```

Comment: If the order of ingredients does not matter, just use a switch statement inside a single `each` loop.

Comment: @Gone Coding they do matter unfortunately its the way the recipe is created

Comment: I get the feeling this is an XY problem. What is the overall aim of your code? To show just one recipe using details of specific properties from that feed? If so, you really should reduce the feed to only required information and return as a dictionary key'ed by the ID

Comment: I have an unordered list and for this particular recipe, i am pulling in product names used from the DB as the ingredients. So this unordered list for "pumpkin risotto" is on a page and im pulling in product names from the DB that are used in the recipe.

Comment: Are you in control of the ingredients feed?

Comment: yeah i can edit the list but not the JSON DB. and it must stay in the order listed above

Comment: So you are downloading a 400kb feed just to get a few names. Yes this is not the way to do it :) JSON is all about transferring the minimum amount of data needed. Better to have a separate feed URL, where you provide the IDs and it returns appropriate details of that/those products *only*. Even 3 separate Ajax calls will be far faster than transferring 400kb

Comment: @GoneCoding That isn't true. If you have a satellite connection, you can expect around 2000ms of roundtrip time. Or ping. If it takes 1 second to download 400kb (assuming a connection above 2Mbps), you saved a few seconds by not sending 3 requests. BUT! I agree with everything else. Use JSON to send the minimal information as possible.

Comment: For you, it would be better to use vanilla javascript inside "success" function. Search for your IDs inside one single for loop, use if-else statements. Additionally you can check inside the loop if all 3 IDs have been found so break it for optimization purpose.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: I don't know about your situation, but we do not code for satellite connections, with a 2 second ping, as our default type of user connection :)

Comment: @GoneCoding My situation usually is a 130mbps link, with 13ms ping to the server. Sometimes, I have a 25mbps down and 28mbps up. Very rarely I have a 5kbps link, over an EDGE connection. I usually code for the "average" 2-4mbps link. Which is very common. I don't code thinking about the ping, since it varies widely.